# Chomsky Normal Form- Theory of computation

Tags: computer-science, chomsky-normal-form

I want to change the grammar in to Chomsky Normal Form(CNF).

This is example

```
S--> AB | ɛ

A--> aASb | a

B--> bS
```

I try to solve this

```
S --> [A] [B]

[A] --> [aA] [Sb] | [a]

[aA] --> [a] A

[Sb] --> s [b]

[a] --> a

[b] --> b
```

I am not sure about the answer. Could anybody tell me if it is right or wrong?

Comment: Not quite the correct forum for your question. Try posting it here : http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your answer does not generate the empty word.

Comment: @Nico: Absolutely not. cstheory is a site for *research level* questions. Also basic CS questions have always been on topic here.

Comment: @sepp2k - My apologies then :)

Answer (score 1):

One mistake is that you removed the `S --> ɛ` transition. You need that (`S --> ɛ` is specifically allowed in CNF, even though `AnyNonTerminalOtherThanS --> ɛ` is not).

Then the rule `[A] --> [a]`, should be `[A] --> a` because if you have only one item on the RHS, it needs to be a terminal.

```
[aA] --> [a] A
[Sb] --> s [b]
```

These two seem like typos as `A` and `s` don't exist. You probably meant:

```
[aA] --> [a] [A]
[Sb] --> [S] [b]
```

Other than that, what you have is correct.

Comment: @ sepp2k- I am sorry but I did not include [A] --> [a] rule as you mentioned earlier. Although I got your point that if on RHS there is only one item then it should be terminal.

Comment: @sepp2K- Hi!. I have a request. I asked a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143186/example-of-non-linear-unambiguous-and-non-deterministic-cfl. - Can clear my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

To write Chomsky normal form to the above question..
Get the form to either S->AB (or) S->aB

[aA] --> [a] [A]
[Sb] --> [S] [b]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Chomsky normal form][1]

Click on this to see the example of chomsky normal form
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F44H0.jpg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).