# Example of Non-Linear, UnAmbiguous and Non-Deterministic CFL?

Tags: finite-automata, automata, computation-theory, formal-languages, chomsky-hierarchy

In the Chomsky classification of formal languages, I need some examples of `Non-Linear, Unambiguous and also Non-Deterministic` Context-Free-Language(N-CFL)?

1. **Linear Language**: For [which Linear grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar) is possible( ⊆ CFG) e.g.
     L<sub>1</sub> = {a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | n ≥ 0 }
2. **Deterministic Context Free Language(D-CFG)**: For which Deterministic Push-Down-Automata(D-PDA) is possible e.g.
   L<sub>2</sub> = {a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>c<sup>m</sup> | n ≥ 0, m ≥ 0 }
       L<sub>2</sub> is  unambiguous.

> A CF grammar that is [not linear is nonlinear](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=hsxDiWvVdBcC&pg=PA210&lpg=PA210&dq=A%20CF%20grammar%20that%20is%20not%20linear%20is%20nonlinear.&source=bl&ots=rcItUgWkbU&sig=27t5VDwFpWxRt35whi7E4FlL1cE&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).
>     **L**<sub>**nl**</sub>  = {w: n<sub>a</sub>(w) = n<sub>b</sub>(w)} is also a **Non-Linear CFG**.

--
3. 
**Non-Deterministic Context Free Language(N-CFG)**: For which `only Non-Deterministic Push-Down-Automata(N-PDA)` is possible e.g.
   L<sub>3</sub> = {ww<sup>R</sup> | w ∈ {a, b}<sup>*</sup> }
   L<sub>3</sub> is also Linear CFG.

--4. **Ambiguous CFL**:   CFL for which `only ambiguous CFG is possible`
 L<sub>4</sub> = {a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>c<sup>m</sup> | n ≥ 0, m ≥ 0 } U {a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>m</sup>c<sup>m</sup> | n ≥ 0, m ≥ 0 }
   L<sub>4</sub> is both non-linear and Ambiguous CFG And Every Ambigous CFL \subseteq N-CFL.

**My Question is:**
Whether all non-linear, Non-Deterministic CFL are Ambiguous? If not then 
I need a example that is non-linear, non-deterministic CFL and also unambiguous?

**Given Venn-diagram below:**

> [image]

Also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225302/example-of-non-linear-unambiguous-and-non-deterministic-cfl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### "IN CONTEXT OF CHOMSHY CLASSIFICATION OF FORMAL LANGUAGE"

(1)   **L<sub>3</sub>** = {ww<sup>R</sup> | w ∈ {a, b}<sup>*</sup> }

- Language L<sub>3</sub>  is a Non-Deterministic Context Free Language, its also Unambiguous and Liner language.

(2)  **L<sub>p</sub>** is language of parenthesis matching. There are two terminal symbols "(" and ")".
Grammar for L<sub>p</sub> is:

```
S → SS
S → (S)
S → ()
```

- This language is nonlinear, deterministic and unambiguous too.

Language **L** that is union of L<sub>p</sub> and L<sub>3</sub> is unambiguous, nonlinear (due to L<sub>p</sub>), and non-deterministic (due to L<sub>3</sub>) (Assuming language symbols for both languages are different).

This Language is an example of language in Venn-diagram for which I marked `??`.

Also the correct diagram is below:

[**An ambiguous context free language also be a liner context free**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252454/in-context-of-chomskhy-classification-of-formal-languages)

> [image: dcf]