# How to determine which class these languages belong to?

Tags: automation, context-free-grammar, regular-language, turing-machines, pushdown-automaton

{WW} - Decidable but not Context free
{WW^R} - Context Free, but not in Regular
Σ* - Regular language
How can you determine which class they belong to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be my answer helpful to you:

> **L<sub>1</sub>** = {ww | w ∈ {a, b}<sup>*</sup> }

is not context Free Language because a (Push down Automata) PDA is not possible (even Non-Deterministic-PDA ). Why? suppose you push first `w` in stack. To match second `w` with first `w` you have to push first `w` in reverse order (either you need to match second `w` in reverse order with stack content) that is not possible with stack (and we can't read input in reverse order). Although its decidable because be can draw a `Turing Machine` for L<sub>1</sub> that always half after finite number of steps.

> **L<sub>3</sub>** = {ww<sup>R</sup> | w ∈ {a, b}<sup>*</sup> }

Language L<sub>3</sub> is a Non-Deterministic Context Free Language, because `n-PDA` is possible but Finite Automate is not possible for L<sub>3</sub>. you can also proof this using Pumping Lemma for Regular Languages.

> `Σ*` - Regular Language(RL)

`Σ*` is Regular Expression (RE) e.g 
if `Σ = {a, b}  then RE is  (a + b)*`  RE is possible only for RLs.

The examples in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143186/example-of-non-linear-unambiguous-and-non-deterministic-cfl) may be more helpful to you.

Comment: definitely! been waiting for answer for a while. thank you so much for lending me a hand!!!!