# Is the language {0^n 1^n 0^k | k != n} context free?

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, regular-language, pushdown-automaton

I believe this language isn't context free, because there is no chance that a PDA could compare 2 blocks of 0's and 1's of the same length and also remember it's length for later use.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to prove it.

I tried using the pumping lemma to no avail...

I've also tried to assume by contradiction that the language is context free and use the fact that the intersection of a context free language with a regular language is also context free (by finding some mysterious regular language L), and surprisingly (or not) - all my efforts were in vain...

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Is the language { 0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup>0<sup>k</sup> | k != n} context free?

**No**, the language L = { 0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup>0<sup>k</sup> | k!=n } is **not a context free language**. Also, [Class of Regular Languages is subset of class Context free languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143186/example-of-non-linear-unambiguous-and-non-deterministic-cfl).

You Idea using `PDA` is correct and obvious way to show that language is not context free. 
And we can't draw `PDA` for language  0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup>0<sup>k</sup> because after matching prefix 0<sup>n</sup> to 1<sup>n</sup> stack become empty, then we don't have stored information to check weather suffix 0<sup>K</sup> are equal to `n` or not.

**HINT:** For formal proofs

- **First**

> L = {0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup>0<sup>k</sup> | k!=n } now complement of L is L<sup>'</sup>.
>
> L<sup>'</sup> = {{0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup>0<sup>n</sup>} that is well known context sensitive language (can be proof).

And **the complement of a context-sensitive language is itself context-sensitive.**

- **Second**

**For Pumping Lemma:**

> L = {0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup>0<sup>k</sup> | k!=n } is Union of L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub>, Where
>   L<sub>1</sub> =  {0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup>0<sup>k</sup> | k > n } and 
>   L<sub>2</sub> =  {0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup>0<sup>k</sup> | k < n },
>
> **L = L<sub>1</sub>   U L<sub>2</sub>**

L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub>  both are  non-context-free Language. and **union of two non-context free languages are non-context-free.**( that can easily proof by grammar)

---

Also, **The union, concatenation of two context-sensitive languages is context-sensitive.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer Grijesh. But I need a more formal proof (it's for a homework question). Do you guys (and girls) have any idea how to prove it ?

Comment: @Robert777 yes formal proof is possible.

Comment: Yes, I would love to see how to solve it with the pumping lemma !

Comment: @Robert777 I updated my answer with useful HINTS. Now Try and let me know if its still difficult.

Comment: @Robert777 Welcome Robert! :)