# Can a Regular Language have a Linear Bounded Automaton

Tags: automata, automata-theory

As the question states:

I am trying to understand automata.  Can every regular language have a linear bounded automaton?

Comment: Probably be better asked on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes. [regular language is subset of almost every formal language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143186/example-of-non-linear-unambiguous-and-non-deterministic-cfl?answertab=votes#tab-top) even for context sensitive language we have Linear Bounded Automato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have Linear Bounded Automata for each and every regular languages. Regular languages are proper subset of **Context Sensitive Languages**. CSL is the language associated with **Linear Bounded Automata** (LBA). For more information on hierarchy of classes of formal grammars and languages read about `Chomsky Hierarchy`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy