# How to check if a language is regular, context-free, det. context-free or type-0

Tags: regular-language, fsm, context-free-language, chomsky-hierarchy

I have to decide for several languages whether they are **regular, context-free, det. context-free or type-0**. I understand how to show a language not to be regular (using the pumping lemma), but how to decide it for the other language types very fast?
The first language is

`{a,b,c}* \ {a^n b^n c^n | n is element of natural numbers}`

Comment: "I understand how to show a language to be regular (using the pumping lemma)" -- **NO** Pumping lemma **doesn't** shows that a language **is** a regular language. Pumping lemma shows that a language is **not** a regular language. **Pumping lemma is necessary but not a sufficient property for regular language**.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It was a wording mistake, of course the pumping lemma shows that a language is not regular. Do you have a solution for my whole problem?

Comment: I think you need something like `language -- [ tool ] --> 'type of language'` ??

Comment: Yes, but I have to find out the language type by hand in an exam. The questions are possibly multiple choice.

Comment: yes, that is what for this whole subject is - classification of formal languages - theory of formal language. check  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13648491/1673391).